# How do I check if I am pausing or exiting the application for android

Tags: android, service, android-activity

I am currently writing an app for android that i need to start the service when I exit or pause the application. What should i do? In my application, every time when I click a thing, it will go to another activity, so i cannot put the startservice to the onpause inside those activity. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the Activity life cycle here:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Android doesn't exit the activity when you start a new one, it just pauses it. So starting the service inside onPause() should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

According to android life cycle, `onPause()` method will call as a first indication that user is leaving your activity. It may leave or not. So as per your requirement you can `startService.` But make sure don't put heavy code inside as it may effect user experience.

Comment: But what if i have several activities? Coz I just want my service start when i am not in the application.

Comment: That means you want to start service when there is no ui visible?

Comment: Ys. Because in my application, i want to keep update location. When i am not in the application, I also want to get the location update.

Comment: then you can start service in `onStop()` method as `onDestroy()` is not ideal place for starting service

Comment: Do you put the service in all the activities' onStop()??

Comment: I have not requirement of this kind. But ya if i have i choose `onStop()`

Answer (score 0):

By overriding this methods you can check if your app is onPause or onDestroy

```
protected void onPause() {
    Log.i("Status", "onPause");
    super.onPause();
}

protected void onDestroy() {
            Log.i("Status", "onDestroy");
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When Activity is no longer visible, it calls `onStop()`. But still we can not be sure if app is destroyed as Android OS internally handles it. So try following steps to find if you app is in `background`:

1. Get the running task info using

   ```
   ActivityManager am = (ActivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
   List<RunningTaskInfo> tasks = am.getRunningTasks(1);
   ```
2. If tasks list is not empty, check if running taks belongs to your app. If it belongs, then return true to the calling function, where you can start your service ; else return `false`

   ```
    if (!tasks.isEmpty()) {
      ComponentName topActivity = tasks.get(0).topActivity;
     if (!topActivity.getPackageName().equals(context.getPackageName()))
     {
        return true;
     }
   ```

Edit : This may be helpful : **http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityManager.html#getRunningAppProcesses**

Comment: Do I need to put this in all the activity onStop()? Since i have several activities

Comment: Why don't you try creating a `MainActivity` where you could override its `onStop()` method and `extend` all other activities from this. So that you need not write it for all activities.