# How to open app in notification in android?

Tags: android, notifications, push-notification

In my app, when completing a task in async file, it shows a notification with this code

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context.getApplicationContext(), 0, new Intent(), 0);

    Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(context)
    .setContentTitle("Complete")
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
    .setContentIntent(pIntent)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
    .build();

    notificationManager.notify(0, noti);
```

The problem is when I click the notification, nothing happens. Basically I want it so that, if the app is already open and the user clicks the notification, then nothing should open. If the app is not open (which means its still running but minimized) then I want it to open the app, like maximize it.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need an `Intent`, sample code:

```
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) context
            .getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    Notification notification = new Notification(icon, message, when);

    Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(context, MainActivity.class);

    notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP
            | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    PendingIntent intent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0,
            notificationIntent, 0);

    notification.setLatestEventInfo(context, title, message, intent);
    notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
    notificationManager.notify(0, notification);
```

This will open your `MainActivity`

Comment: This works, but is there a way so that, if the notification is clicked, it checks if the app is running or exited. If its exited, then I want to open another class, otherwise just maximize it.

Comment: Maybe you can check here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15239889/how-do-i-check-if-i-am-pausing-or-exiting-the-application-for-android